# Определённое действие при выборе элемента в Dropdown [Unity C#]

Tags: c#, unity3d

[Unity C#]
Здравствуйте, столкнулся с проблемой:
Мне надо выполнять определённое действие при выборе определённого объекта в Dropdown, к пример кода:

```
public Dropdown dropdown;
public string isSelected;

public void click()
{
    if(dropdown.//тот метод, который определяет, выбран ли "Object A")
        {
        clickIfSelectedObjectA();
    }

    if (dropdown.//тот метод, который определяет, выбран ли "Object B")
        {
        clickIfSelectedObjectB();
    }
}

//Что происходит при клике, если выбран "Object A"
public void clickIfSelectedObjectA()
{
    isSelected = "Выбран 'Object A'";
}

//Что происходит при клике, если выбран "Object B"
public void clickIfSelectedObjectB()
{
    isSelected = "Выбран 'Object B'";
}
```

Comment: И в чём ваша проблема?

Comment: VladD, проблема в том, что я не могу разобраться, как сделать данный код          P.S. Я новичок)

Comment: @Квайат, можете описать задачу, которую вам нужно решить подробнее? Тогда я смогу подробнее описать варианты её решения.

Comment: @M.Green, есть GameObject Dropdown, и надо при выборе "Object A" выполнять метод "clickIfSelectedObjectA", а при выборе "Object B" - "clickIfSelecteOobjectB"

Comment: @Квайат, что значит "при выборе"? У вас есть выпадающий список и кнопка? Кнопка должна делать либо А, либо Б, в зависимости от того, что сейчас выбрано в списке? Или вам нужно что-то делать сразу по факту выбора? Т.е. выбрали А и сразу же вызвалось А?

Comment: @M.Green, вы в самом начале правильно поняли

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Давайте попробую описать логику действий.
У вас должен быть класс, который имеет ссылку на *Dropdown*. Сам *Dropdown* имеет поле *.value*, в котором можно получить индекс текущего выбранного элемента.

В итоге при нажатии кнопки вы получаете текущее значение, и с помощью, например, банального перебора if-ми выбираете вызов нужного метода. Или можете использовать switch-case.
Если же вам нужно вызывать что-то сразу после смены элемента - можно подписаться на событие изменения выбора *.isValueChange*

[Документация по Dropdown, с примером](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Dropdown.html)
[API Dropdown](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Dropdown.html)
[API Dropdown.isValueChange](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Dropdown-onValueChanged.html)
[API Dropdown.value](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Dropdown-value.html)

В вашем примере можно сделать так:

```
public Dropdown dropdown;
public string isSelected;

public void click()
{
    int index = dropdown.value;
    switch (index):
    { 
           case 0:
                clickIfSelectedObjectA();
                break;

           case 1:
                clickIfSelectedObjectB();
                break;
    }
}

//Что происходит при клике, если выбран "Object A"
public void clickIfSelectedObjectA()
{
    isSelected = "Выбран 'Object A'";
}

//Что происходит при клике, если выбран "Object B"
public void clickIfSelectedObjectB()
{
    isSelected = "Выбран 'Object B'";
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое)